# Generating QQ-plot for custom random number generator

Tags: r, random, plot

I would like to generate a QQ-plot for a (discrete) custom random number generator. The generator only has a probability function predefined and I use this function to generate a table which I then search in based on a value from `U(0,1)` (essentially using the inverse-transform method, with a binary search).

The problem is, I have no way of generating a set of data, which could be used to verify the random numbers I generate myself -- is there a way to generate a set of values which may be used to generate a proper QQ-plot, with just the probability function?

So far I've tried by creating a histogram and plotting it against the probabilities of the distribution... which is not what I should be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, quantile plots are more closely related to CDF, rather than PDF. It is kind of reverse-axis CDF_theory vs CDF_sample

> is there a way to generate a set of values which may be used to generate a proper QQ-plot, with just the probability function?

Sure. I did it in python, and might dig the code I did and translate it to **R**

In mean time, here is quick but well done description: http://onlinestatbook.com/2/advanced_graphs/q-q_plots.html

Comment: Thanks. I didn't actually have to do this, but just wanted to for the sake of completeness. In the end, I didn't have space for a lot of things in my report so it wasn't a problem leaving this out.

Comment: @Clearer well, I was looking around wrt some unrelated issue and found native **R** package for the question asked - qqmath. Take a look at http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/lattice/qqmath and tell m what you think